# Smith (2010a, 2010b) instead of Smith (2010a, b) during in-line citation

Tags: citing, natbib

I am using natbib package for my writing.

For example, Smith has 2 papers, both published in 2010. 
I have labeled them as Sm1 and sm2 in my .bib file.
Now when I cite the papers using \citet{Sm1,Sm2}, it produces Smith (2010a, b). But I want it to be as Smith (2010a, 2010b).
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd patch `\NAT@citex` to avoid the check of the year, so you don't need to know the year in advance. It will just work in every case.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{sma,
 author={Smith, J.},
 title={A},
 journal={B},
 year={2014},
}
@article{smb,
 author={Smith, J.},
 title={C},
 journal={D},
 year={2014},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% patch \NAT@citex to always use the year
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\NAT@citex}
  {\ifx\NAT@last@yr\NAT@year}
  {\iffalse}
  {}{}
\xpatchcmd{\NAT@citex}
  {\ifx\NAT@last@yr\NAT@year}
  {\iffalse}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\citep{sma,smb}

\citet{sma,smb}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

As usual, the `filecontents*` environment is just to make the example self-contained.

[image]

Explanation. The `\NAT@citex` command is the main part of the process; at two places it does

```
\ifx\NAT@last@yr\NAT@year
  <something if the current citation has the same year as the preceding one>
\else
  <otherwise>
\fi
```

With the patch we change the conditional (first line) to `\iffalse`, so the “true” branch will never be followed.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the two entries' keys are `sm1` and `sm2`, you can achieve your objective by writing

```
\citeauthor{sm1} (\citeyear{sm1}, \citeyear{sm2})
```

Remark: The `natbib` package features the options `sort`, `compress`, and `sort&compress`, but they seem to be mostly geared toward numerical-style citation callouts. For authoryear-style citation callouts, the package does not appear to provide options such as `nosort` or `nocompress` -- hence the need for the cumbersome-looking code provided above.

Comment: Nice & Simple Solution!

Comment: Another thing, for a single citation like \citep {sm1}, I get (Smith,2010). Is there any way if I want it as (Smith 2010) instead of (Smith,2010)? I just want a blank space instead of the comma.

Comment: @Tnoor If you want to remove the comma between the author name an the year, add `\setcitestyle{aysep={}}` to your preamble.